# Line wrapping in a PDF document

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, pdf-format

Writing:

```
list = ConstantArray[0, {2, 35}];
doc = 
  CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[TableForm[list, TableSpacing -> {2, 2}], "Output"]];
Export["test.pdf", doc];
```

I get the following pdf document:

[image]

where it is evident that it does not automatically go to the end, but cuts part of the table.

Any suggestions for automatic line wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableSpacing -> {2, 1}` to shrink the width.

Alternatively, to line wrap after 24 items.

```
doc = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[TableForm[
    Flatten[Partition[#, UpTo[24]] & /@ list, 1],
    TableSpacing -> {2, 2}], "Output"]]
```

**Edit**

To automatically adjust

```
cellsize[n_] := ImageDimensions[Rasterize[
   cell = ExpressionCell[TableForm[
      Flatten[Partition[#, UpTo[n]] & /@ list, 1],
      TableSpacing -> {2, 2}], "Output"]]]

list = ConstantArray[0, {2, 35}];

x = 24;

cellsize[24]
```

> {582, 80}

582 is the minimum width.  Now making a list with larger items.

```
list = ConstantArray[1234, {2, 35}];

cellsize[24]
```

> {1086, 80}

```
While[First[cellsize[x]] > 582, --x]
doc = CreateDocument[cell];
```